# Message order with multiple publishers to same latched topic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, topic, latch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Scenario:

- a node A publishes "hello" to a latched topic /x with queue size 1
- then a node B publishes "world" to the same latched topic /x with queue size 1

Because of the latched topics, I assume a late subscriber will receive both "hello" and then "world", correct?

But is the order guaranteed, will he always receive "hello", then "world" ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304013/message-order-with-multiple-publishers-to-same-latched-topic/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-09-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) :

> latch [optional]
>
> Enables "latching" on a connection.
> When a connection is latched, the last
> message published is saved and
> automatically sent to any future
> subscribers that connect. This is
> useful for slow-changing to static
> data like a map. **Note that if there
> are multiple publishers on the same
> topic, instantiated in the same node,
> then only the last published message
> from that node will be sent, as
> opposed to the last published message
> from each publisher on that single
> topic.**

So with your scenario your assumption is correct. For the order, I tried your scenario and there wasn't any specific ordrer when subscribing to the topic so no the order isn't guaranteed.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-24**:
I don't believe this answers @knxa's question: he asks about *multiple* nodes, while the wiki you quote discusses multiple publishers in the *same* node.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-24**:
I understood the end of the quote as the case with multiples node but when reading it again I might have made a mistake. But anyway I tried his scenario using two different nodes and the messages weren't the same order each time.